# Notice: Undefined offset: 2 ,while fetching the data from csv using php

Tags: php, csv

I was trying to fetch the data from csv to display using php.Here is the code

```
<?PHP

    $file_handle = fopen("dept.csv", "r");

    while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

        $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
        print ($line_of_text[0]) . "   ". ($line_of_text[1]). ($line_of_text[2]) . "<BR>";

    }

    fclose($file_handle);

?>
```

I am getting the output but getting a notice msg :

> Notice: Undefined offset: 2

How to solve it?

Comment: Show us your csv file. In one line you don't have 3 columns

Comment: And empty lines typically have no columns at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't post such questions without providing the file
2. Appears that there are either only 2 columns in csv file or 1 of the entries does not have the third column filled in
3. If you don't want to look into the file you can do this:

   ```
   $file_handle = fopen("dept.csv", "r");

   while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

       $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
       print ($line_of_text[0]) . "   ". ($line_of_text[1]);
       if (isset($line_of_text[2]))
            print($line_of_text[2]);
       print ("<BR>");

   }

   fclose($file_handle);
   ```

Comment: sorry danny, it is my mistake. I have a empty column